# Mach-O Linker Error - Assertion failed: (cfiStartsArray[i] != cfiStartsArray[i-1])

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, dji-sdk

The demo app in the newly released SDK for the DJI Phantom doesn't build, due to a linker error:

```
Assertion failed: (cfiStartsArray[i] != cfiStartsArray[i-1]), function parse, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-241.9/src/ld/parsers/macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 1745.
```

In my searching for reasons why I have come across one suggested reason - an incompatibility between gcc and the OS X system linker - which makes me wonder whether other people are seeing this problem, and not just for this demo app. Anyone?

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 on OS X 10.10.1.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thanks to DJI support I found that targeting a device rather than the simulator resolves the linker issue, so that gets me going again. I've seen other people cite that linker error when trying to build unrelated projects, without a clear resolution, so it would be good to know why, or to get a clearer linker error message.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings and change the compiler to "LLVM 6.0" in Build options under Build settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The compiler is already set to "Apple LLVM 6.0".

Answer (score 0):

In the Build settings menu, I experimented with the Mach-O type under "linking options". That took away the error with me.

I am working on a DJI as well, but I also got the error when I compiled a " Hello World" app I made on a previous Mac OS release.